# What's the benefit of software pipeline?

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

Optimizing compiler usually consider to do instruction scheduling by software pipeline. But as there is hardware pipeline, I am wondering what's the advantage of software pipeline scheduling?

Comment: The compiler has a bigger picture of the overall computation than the hardware can have, so it may be able to improve performance more by software scheduling, leaving the final tweaks to the hardware scheduling.

Answer (score 3):

In some cases (CPU specific) execution speed may depend on the execution order. With software pipelining, compiler reorders your statements to have the optimal order, if it is possible to do so without affecting the final result.

The optimal order may depend on the existing hardware pipeline, or some registers may be possible to use more optimally under certain order of execution, or the like.

Comment: Software Pipelining is more than just *reordering* or rather scheduling instructions. In particular, it will increase code size and it will increase register pressure.

Answer (score 2):

Software pipelining can make loops execute faster. In some cases really faster.

For example:

```
num = 100;
i = 0;
loop:
load r0 sp+i;
add r2 r1 r0;
i++;
if ( i < num) goto loop
```

In this example the add instruction has to wait until `r0` has the value loaded from memory. If the latency is say 3 cycles. Then there will be an overhead of 3 cycle per iteration for the execution of this loop. This can be a significant overhead. By software-pipelining this overhead can be reduced a little bit.

```
num = 100;
load r0 sp+0;
i=0;
loop:
add r2 r1 r0;
i++;
load r0 sp+i
if (i < num) goto loop
```

In the second case when the program enters the loop it already has the value in `r0` when the `add` instruction is executed. In each iteration by the time program reaches `add` instruction the value is there in `r0`. So the latency is reduced.

PS: I have just used mnemonics to explain the idea. This is not a real assembly language of some architecture.